# When people want to manipulate a pointer in a function, why do they pass in a double pointer?

Tags: c++, optimization

When looking over code I've noticed that people pass into a function a pointer-to-a-pointer when they want to manipulate a pointer.

Example: I see things like

```
void increment_if_J (char ** ptr)
{
    if (**ptr == 'J')
       ++(*ptr);
}
```

But doesn't it make more sense to pass in a reference to a pointer?

```
void increment_if_J (char * & ptr)
{
    if (*ptr == 'J')
       ++(ptr);
}
```

That way you aren't creating an extra variable and you don't have to wreck your brain by thinking about the confusing "pointer-to-a-pointer" logic.

Comment: Since this isn't a C question, please don't tag it with `[c]`.

Comment: I think this just depends on which code you're looking at. I've seen plenty of examples on both sides. The pointer-to-pointer version may be popular with more C-centric coders, who don't think to use references.

Comment: You can consider `void increment_if_J (char ** ptr)` as _old c-style_.

Comment: You've tagged this with two languages. You'd usually prefer a reference in the language that has references, but not in the other.

Comment: I would return a pointer with the new value. `char* increment(char*);`, in both C and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged the question with both `[c]` and `[c++]`.

- In C, the answer is simple: there are no references, so the second approach is not an option.
- In C++, both are valid and are largely a stylistic choice. Some people might feel that the first would make it clearer at the call site that the pointer might get modified by the function. Some might prefer the first because they are used to coding in C. Some might prefer the second because of reasons you cite. And so on...

Comment: It's worth noting that in the `char*&` variant, the reference cannot be null, so you can omit a null check. (The referenced pointer might still be null, though.)  In the `char**` variant you may have to null-check the pointer and the pointed-to pointer.

Comment: @cdhowie Well it can be null, but it's up to the caller to ensure it isn't.

Comment: @NeilKirk If the address of a reference is null then someone somewhere triggered UB. (`static_cast<int &>(*static_cast<int *>(nullptr))` is UB.) So it can only be null in a program whose behavior is undefined, and if we're allowing that then we can't reason about anything.

Comment: Yes something bad has happened, but I think "references are magically protected from being null" is misleading.

Comment: "References are protected from being null in programs that have defined behavior" is good enough. Again, if you're allowing UB into the mix you have more serious problems.

Comment: Put it another way: If you allow UB to be considered then dereferencing a pointer could cause music to start playing if UB was triggered earlier in the program, but you don't see anyone bringing that up every time someone dereferences a pointer because you can't reason about UB; it's not worth considering.

Comment: @cdhowie Let's say I take parameter `char ** p` and assert p is not null, as the function can't work if it is. Now I read these comments and change the function to `char *& p` and remove the assert, thinking my code is safer when actually it is less protected against error.

Comment: No, it's not protected against error even if you assert that `&p != nullptr` because the only way the assert *could possibly fail* is if you invoke UB somewhere. Adding a null test will only protect you from *one particular outcome* of UB. Change compilers and the UB could manifest in a completely different way, one the assert will not catch, or one that may not even make it to the assert before doing something crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Because every C parameter passing is [call by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass-by-value#Call_by_value). This is different in C++, which has *references*.

Answer (score 0):

Although passing by double pointer has mostly been used for compatibility reasons with pre-existing C API code (no references), there are cases (aside from coding style) in which a function might prefer to modify its arguments directly instead of allocating an additional stack local one:

```
void increment_if_J(char ** ptr)
{
    // I can use ptr to do some other processing first
    char** original = ptr;
    char other_str[] = "Jenny";
    char* contrivedptr = other_str;
    ptr = &contrivedptr;
    **ptr = 'F'; // other_str is now "Fenny"
    ptr = original;

    if (**ptr == 'J')
        ++(*ptr);
}

void increment_if_J_ref(char * & ptr)
{
    // Can't directly use ptr without modifying the referred memory

    if (*ptr == 'J')
        ++(ptr);
}

int main(){

    char str[] = "Jerry";
    char* ptr = str;
    increment_if_J(&ptr); // ptr points to "erry"

    ptr = str;
    increment_if_J_ref(ptr); // ptr points to "erry"

    return 0;
}
```

This isn't a "*promote-the-contriveness*" technique but might come in handy under special memory-constrained circumstances.